# Bamboo Unable to publish artifact

Tags: svn, build, bamboo, artifacts

I have a question about artifacts configuration; I'm working with automatic build using code source files from SVN.

**Rq: all the tasks I used in Bamboo are DOS scripts.**

After a successful build, I configured Artifacts by putting /*.BIN in the Copy pattern field.

the generated file (BIN file) is located under my workspace (c:\workspace\Bin) that's why I modified the bamboo.artifacts.directory in bamboo.cfg.xml file by: "C:\workspace", and I putted "Bin" under Location  in the bamboo artifact definition;

However, after correctly building the project, I found in the log file the following line: **"Unable to publish artifact [XXXXXX]: null" and there is no generated artifact.**

Could someone help me please !!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely issue is either permissions or that bamboo doesn't have write access to a directory outside of the bamboo workspace. Remember it is running as the user you run the bamboo service as.  Your workspace (where you code) and bamboo's workspace (where the build happens) are two different things.  You would be better off using the default config which puts the bamboo shared artifacts in a bamboo workspace artifact storage, and then inserting a simple script to copy them to whereever you want them afterwards.

Other common problems include not defining the artifact correctly either by fat fingering the name or path, or by not specifying the correct location/name of the artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I found that artifact publication can fail without an error if there is not enough disk space on the server (if using local storage). You can check the "Disk space free" on the "System information" page in your Bamboo configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my system. The problem ended up being that the firewalls had changed on our main Bamboo server.  The artifacts were created on the remote agent but could not be sent over to the main server for archiving.  Re-opening the main Bamboo port to the remote agents solved the problem.